# please explain to me nature of this error showing up when setting static variable

Tags: php

What I wanted to do is to set static `$variable` to `'new value'`. This is my code:

```
class myobj {

    static protected $variable = null;

    static function test() {
        static::variable = 'new value'
    }
}

$obj = new myobj();
$obj->test();
```

But an error shows up:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in D:\!TC\www\error.php on line 8
```

Comment: can you tell us which line line 8 is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
self::$variable = 'new value';
```

instead of:

```
static::variable = 'new value'
```

BTW I strongly encourage you to use an IDE able to directly tell you basic syntax errors, like [**Aptana Studio**](http://aptana.com/) or [**PHPStorm**](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/).

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the dollar sign and a colon, and should use `self` to reference the data member `$variable`:

```
self::$variable = 'new value';
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `self`:

```
class myobj {
  static protected $variable = null;
  static function test() {
    self::$variable = 'new value';
  }
}
```